# how can I reset/modify Wordpress password

Tags: wordpress

I ashed a question [How to make Wordpress independent of hostname](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532530/how-to-make-wordpress-independent-of-hostname) recently, and followed the advice by editing the mysql details.

This seemed quite successful and the Wordpress installation seemed to work.

I wanted to run `wp-admin` but could no longer login with the password.

I note passwords are stored in the database encrypted, so I guess this may involve the hostname.

My question is how can I reset/modify the password?
There is a option to reset password by email, but this could not send an email (email probably never been used)

Comment: Changing the hostname does not invalidate existing passwords, only cookies. Something else is wrong. If you missed a spot updating the name it may try to log you in to the old location, which fails, but otherwise I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: You can just use phpmyadmin and enter a new password using MD5 function. Quick research yields a lot of [howto](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/reset-wordpress-admin-password/)'s.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened to the password (possibly it didn't work because it is salted) but I managed to reset with the following:-

Run mysql with `sudo mysql  -u root -p`
enter password

```
use wordpress;
SELECT ID, user_login, user_pass FROM wp_users;
```

Note ID of user

run

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5('password') WHERE ID = 1;
```